# Android app child activity not restored after press home/task-switcher

Tags: android

I have a main activity which creates a child activity when a button is pressed.

If I press the task-manager or home button when the child activity is displayed, the child activity is destroyed, and I get onSaveInstanceState then onDestroy called (for the child).

When I switch back to my app, the user is returned to the root activity and the child is not restored.  The only notification I receive is the main activity onResume.

I've tried setting the alwaysRetainTaskState flag in my root activity, but doesn't help.

Can any one offer any advice?

```
<application
    android:name=".Application"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".GameActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:noHistory="true">
        <!--android:theme="@style/AppDialogTheme"-->
    </activity>
</application>

public void onClickStart(View v) {
    ((Application) getApplication()).resetCurrentScore();
    ((Application) getApplication()).resetCurrentLevel();
    ((Application) getApplication()).resetLives();

    Integer level = ((Application) getApplication()).getCurrentLevel();

    if (level <= 3) {
        Intent GameActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GameActivity.class);
        startActivity(GameActivity);
    }
    else {
        Intent SpellGameActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SpellGameActivity.class);
        startActivity(SpellGameActivity);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's likely causing this is your `android:noHistory` attribute in your GameActivity block. This causes the Activity to leave no stack trace, and for `finish()` to be called on it when it leaves the user's view, which is why `onDestroy()` would be called and why the Activity is destroyed.

From the docs:

> android:noHistory
>
> Whether or not the activity should be removed from the activity stack
>   and finished (its finish() method called) when the user navigates away
>   from it and it's no longer visible on screen — "true" if it should be
>   finished, and "false" if not. The default value is "false". A value of
>   "true" means that the activity will not leave a historical trace. It
>   will not remain in the activity stack for the task, so the user will
>   not be able to return to it. In this case, onActivityResult() is never
>   called if you start another activity for a result from this activity.

Comment: That was it!  Thanks!

Comment: No problem! Glad to help!